# PCA with $\mathcal{l}$1-regularization / LASSO with linear constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, computational-mathematics

I want to solve the following optimization problems.

 For some $\lambda>0$, matrix, $X$ and vectors, $\mathbf{v_1}, \mathbf{v_2}, ..., \mathbf{v_k}$
$$\textrm{max}_\mathbf{v}\lambda\|\mathbf{v}\|_1+\mathbf{v}^TX^TX\mathbf{v}$$
s.t.
$$\mathbf{v}\perp\mathbf{v_1}, \mathbf{v_2}, ..., \mathbf{v_k}$$
When $k=0$, this question simplifies to $$\textrm{max}_\mathbf{v}\lambda\|\mathbf{v}\|_1+\mathbf{v}^TX^TX\mathbf{v}$$
without the contraint. This is essentially the LASSO regression with target being all zeros

 Could anyone point me any references, existent work or directions on solving this problem?

Comment: @user619894 yes, I just realize that when $k=0$, this is a LASSO regression :). Thanks.

Comment: You cannot just solve PCA with an $l_1$ regularizer as if it was linear regression or a similar model. If you're looking for ways to impose sparsity [look here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_PCA#Algorithms_for_Sparse_PCA) for options to begin. Also, Python's scipy has some functions for it